# Sending AJAX POST request with serialize without any form inputs

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im sending an ajax request using this code:

```
var frm = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: '/section/' + frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
           CloseModal('', '1');
           LoadModalBody(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
```

So it can pickup all form inputs, but sometimes i'll send a request with no inputs in the form.

How can i still get the post request to send through

Answer (score 2):

Just use an object with key value pairs in place of `data: frm.serialize(),`

For example

```
data:{
   'my-key' : 'my-value',
   'another-key' : 'another-value'
},
```

**Edit**

Also, if there is no form you will need to explicitly set the method:

```
type:'POST',
```

Comment: but i want to use the serialize in some cases